# How to create a free shipping function?

Tags: python

Hello I am very new at python and programming and one of my assignments were to create a cash register or wish list. I am wondering how you can create a free shipping if its > than 25 or 50 I kinda have a small knowledge about it but dont quite get it or not getting the output I want what should I change or add to add a "Free Shipping". This is not needed for the assignment but just want to know how to do it for future references.

```
def main():

    item1 = input(" Item Name ")
    item2 = input(" Item Name 2")
    item3 = input(" Item Name 3")



    var1 = float(input(" Item Cost 1"))
    var2 = float(input(" Item Cost 2"))
    var3 = float(input(" Item Cost 3"))

    # Shipping Handling
    shipping= 5.99

    total = var1 + var2 + var3 
    if total > float(50.00):
        print("Free Shipping")
    tax= total*.065
    subTotal= str(total)

                                                                    # Total of everything 
    totalofEvery=total + float(tax) + float(str(shipping))



    print("Items Ordered:")

    print("")
    print("Items"+"                                            Cost")
    print( item1 + " " + "                                               "+"$" +str(var1,)) +"  "

    print( item2 + " " + "                                               "+"$" +str(var2)) +"  "

    print( item3 + " " + "                                               "+"$" +str(var3)) +"  "
    print(" ")
    print("_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _")
    print("Subtotal: " +"                                       "+"$"+ subTotal)
    print("Shipping Fee" + ":" + "                                    "+"$" + str(float(shipping)))
    print("Tax"+":" + "                                             " +"$" +str(tax))
    print("Here is your order total "+":" +"                       "+"$"+str(totalofEvery))

main()
```

Comment: i don't really understand what you want...Would you like a function to calculate the total cost, shipping include and that will apply the free shipping reduction if necessary?

Comment: You need to do a little more research on what your casting operations are doing. For example, `float(str(shipping))`, `shipping` is created as a `float` on initialization (`shipping= 5.99`). So why would you cast it to a `string` and then back to a `float`?

Comment: It looks like you already have the mechanism in place. you're already checking whether your total is greater than 50, so why not just use that to set your shipping cost to zero at the same time you print? `shipping=0.0` in your existing `if`

Comment: yes @Alexis I seen that i've already created it but im not sure how to put it into the shipping fee section

Comment: @G.Anderson's solution is the easiest: change the value of shipping in the if condition.

Comment: @IFunball thanks for pointing that out it's been a habit of rushing and not looking over

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll simplify G. Anderson's answer. This will solve your shipping problem:

```
if total > float(50.00):
   print("Free Shipping")
   shipping = 0.0 # this is what you need, inside the if statement
```

You also have several syntax errors as well as the odd casting I made a comment about. On line 29, change `str(var1,))` to `str(var1)`.

Move all the second parenthesis to the end of the line on lines 29, 31, and 33.

For example:

```
print( item2 + " " + "                                               "+"$" +str(var2)) +"  "
```

Should be:

```
print( item2 + " " + "                                               "+"$" +str(var2) +"  ")
```

That should make it work as expected.

Edit: For your comment: Use `str.format` See, the following example and replace all your item / var print statements with it. I selected 25 spaces abitrarily to try to match your previous print statement.

```
print("{:<25s}{:>25s}".format(item1, "$" + str(var1)))
```

Comment: also do you know how to make the cost of each items stay on one place an example is like      $32.45 $3.45 $4.45 these numbers would change because of the text size some are bigger than others of the item names and the cost of each items would just move unevenly

Comment: yes but it keeps giving me this error TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' on line 33